# Eloquent belongsToMany not working

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have usual belongsToMany relation (`posts`, `categories`, `category_post`) in Post model:

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Category');
}
```

It's working.

But the same thing with tables `posts`, `options`, `option_post` doesn't work.

```
public function options()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Option');
}
```

I tried different ways: setting relation tables by hand, setting pivot table name etc, but it still doesn't work.

I'm getting nothing with this code in template:

```
    @foreach($post->options() as $option)
        {{ $option->name }}
    @endforeach
```

And no errors.

Comment: Use `DB::getQueryLog()` or some sort of debugger (Clockwork, laravel-debugbar) to determine what query is actually being run, and if that query is correct.

Comment: Can you confirm that the `$post` in question does indeed have associated `options()` in the db?

Comment: Is there a relation in the database between posts, categories, category_post but not between posts, options, option_post?

Comment: Do you have debug turned on in the config?

Comment: mopo922, no db doesn't have any inner relations

Comment: ziGi, no there aren't

Comment: akanevsky, yes for sure

Comment: mopo922, if you're asking whether I have associated values in tables, yes I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be calling the relationship method in your view. You should be calling the [dynamic property](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#dynamic-properties) that will fetch the result of the relationship.

**No:**

```
@foreach($post->options() as $option)
    {{ $option->name }}
@endforeach
```

**YES:**

```
@foreach($post->options as $option)
    {{ $option->name }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: it seems it has helped